# Set correct user/group to Apache server / projects

Tags: permissions, apache2

I cannot set the web projects permissions correctly on webserver Ubuntu 20.04,  Nginx, Apache. It is my first web hosting administration, so forgive me if I do not use the terms correctly.

I have a `sudo` user 'foo'. I manage the server through it.
I use another, not sudo user 'boo' for managing the web projects (nodjs, apache, ....)

The web projects are located at: `/home/boo/apps/blog`, `/home/boo/apps/forum`, ...

I tried different tutorials on setting `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data blog` and readjusting the individual projects, but it doesn't look good to me.

On my old hosting, the web projects are owned by 'boo'

`drwxr-xr-x   7 boo boo 4096 Sep 16 05:59 blog`

Is it mean that the apache server is set to work with 'boo'? How to set it to work like that. It is the best case according to me because 'boo' can edit the projects without `sudo`.

I tried to set it in `/etc/apache2/envvars` without success.

```sh
export APACHE_RUN_USER=boo
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=boo
```

I tried to add 'boo' to the 'www-data' group: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data boo`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

We can set individual group / user for each virtual host with teh help of **The Apache 2 ITK MPM** http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:666>
        ServerName example.com

        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                AssignUserId boo boo
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```